# From Star Trek to the Newest iterations, the Enterprise moves through a starfield in a way that seems to defy physics.

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Watching many space fictions on tv and in films, the effect of moving through a starfield seems to be out of proportion. Given the vast distances between stars, wouldn't the stars be immobile? Instead of zooming past the ships like the classic screen saver?

I considered this may attributed to a warp field in the story, but it happens with slow moving ships too.
The obvious answer is , it looks cool. And it does, until you see seeming impossibility of such an effect is considered. Watch the STNG opening,

the stars appear to be mere  kilometers of the ship as they pass.

Comment: “The obvious answer is , it looks cool. And it does, until you see seeming impossibility of such an effect is considered.” I think it’s still cool.

Comment: the TNG video seems to have two layers - one pretty static starfield that simply pans as the camera does, and then another one near the ship... could be just space dust illuminated by the ship lights?